# What's the meaning of "cracking"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

> “You have no one co-signing your fantasy,’’ Damon says. “It is kind of
> like when you were a kid making a game up in your room. **It’s entirely
> dependent on not cracking.** It was the challenge of the movie and kind
> of why I wanted to do it.’’
>
> (source:
> http://bigstory.ap.org/article/9fab0264d1f0481984b1380e6bc613c7/damon-scott-book-return-space-martian)

I don't have a grasp of the phrase "It's entirely dependent on not cracking"

I looked up the meaning of cracking in the dictionary but I couldn't find the relevant one.

Comment: Hard to say.  "Giving up" or "breaking down under pressure" could be the intended meaning, but doesn't really fit that well.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about *crack*?

Comment: @Drew - Just say no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that here "cracking" has the meaning of **giving up** under pressure (or not giving up in this context). It's about being constant and not abandoning what you've started.